# Google Sheets Script: Use data to make a new tab and export matching information to the new tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that will take a manufacturer's name from a column in one tab, use that name to create a new tab, and export data on all products in the list made by that manufacturer to the newly created tab. The main tab from which the manufacturer names would be pulled, called Pricebook, has around 10,000 lines, with columns like Manufacturer, UPC, and Price. There is another tab called MFG which allows me to choose which manufacturers I'd like to run a report on. I have been able to use the script to create new tabs, but I can't figure out how to get the data from "Pricebook" to transfer over into the newly created tabs. Below is part of my script. The top function creates the new tabs, and the bottom function exports the information to the new tab.

```
function newTabsAndData() { //create tabs based on selected mfgs, move relevant data to each tab
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var main = ss.getSheetByName('PRICEBOOK'); //all pricing data
  var mfgs = ss.getSheetByName('MFGs'); //Manufacutrer's names
  
  mfgs.getRange(2,2,mfgs.getLastRow(),2).copyTo(mfgs.getRange(2,2,mfgs.getLastRow(),2),{contentsOnly:true}); //columns b and c removes formula and pastes only value to same column
  mfgs.getRange(2,1,mfgs.getLastRow(),3).sort([{column:1, ascending:false}, {column:3, ascending:true}]); //sort by True(1) then mfg name(3).
  
  var mfgscvals = mfgs.getRange("C2:C").getValues().filter(String).length; //finds values and last row in MFGs column C to name tabs
  var dataMain = main.getRange(2,1,main.getLastRow(),main.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //range of data from PRICEBOOK to move to new tabs
  var outData = []
  
    for(var i = 1; i < mfgscvals+1; i++){ //look at C on MFGs and collect name one at a time. for = loop the following. java starts at 0, so i = 1 starts on row 2

  var tabName = mfgs.getRange(i+1,3).getValue(); //get name from column 3 of MFGs and create new tab(insert sheet) with that name
  ss.insertSheet(tabName);
    }
}; 

function moveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var main = ss.getSheetByName('PRICEBOOK'); //all pricing data
  var mfgs = ss.getSheetByName('MFGs'); //Manufacutrer's names
  
  mfgs.getRange(2,2,mfgs.getLastRow(),2).copyTo(mfgs.getRange(2,2,mfgs.getLastRow(),2),{contentsOnly:true}); //columns b and c removes formula and pastes only value to same column
  mfgs.getRange(2,1,mfgs.getLastRow(),3).sort([{column:1, ascending:false}, {column:3, ascending:true}]); //sort by True(1) then mfg name(3).
  
  var mfgscvals = mfgs.getRange("C2:C").getValues().filter(String).length; //finds values and last row in MFGs column C to name tabs
  var dataMain = main.getRange(2,1,main.getLastRow(),main.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //range of data from PRICEBOOK to move to new tabs
  var outData = []


  var shts = ss.getSheets();
    for (j = 3; j < shts.length; j++){
    shts[j].getSheetName()
      if (shts[j] == dataMain[2]){
      outData.push(dataMain[0])
    //for (var j in dataMain){
      //if (dataMain[j][2] == tabName){ //loop col 3 of PRICEBOOK, if tabName(mfg name) = dataMain C, then move data to tab with mfg name
      //outData.push(dataMain[j])
  }
  var mfgName = ss.getSheetByName(shts[j]); //moves correct data to first tab, moves data from first tab and second to second tab, 1,2,& 3 to third etc
  mfgName.getRange(mfgName.getLastRow()+1,1,outData.length,outData[0].length).setValues(outData);
  }
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your exact issue? Are there any error messages? Please share a copy of your sheet for testing, please see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you already have names of manufactures on the price list why wouldn't use just the  filter by this column? Add and select a new row at the top of the sheet. Click `Data` > `Create a filter`. Turn on a filter in column with manufacturers. Copy everything. Paste on new sheet. Enjoy.